# binary serialization of types defined in a silverlight assembly

Tags: silverlight, serialization

I have a silverlight assembly which is referenced by a silverlight application and a ASP.Net application.

In the ASP.Net app i need to serialize(Binary) some of the instances of types defined in the silverlight assembly. Can anyone help me with this?

**Edit**

My problem is that i have a silverlight assembly which is used by a silverilght application, a asp.net app and a winforms app, in my asp.net app and winforms app i need to serialize types defined in the shared silverlight assmebly.

**Also on a slightly different note can some one explain why this attribute is needed?**

Comment: is binary serialization strictly needed? Actually the most common way to serialize data and use it across Silverlight application and ASP.NET pages is JSON serialization.

Comment: @zenonych - i am not looking to binary serialize the object in my silverlight app. pls check my question edit have added a little more info.

Comment: I've changed my answer, please look at it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used something called the [sharp serializer](http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html) which is able to binary serialize types without a serializable attribute.

Answer (score 1):

> Also on a slightly different note can
>   some one explain why this attribute is
>   needed?

Lets see:
During serialization BinaryFormatter calls methods of FormatterServices class. One of they is

```
private static MemberInfo[] InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type)
```

This method contains next code:

```
 if (!CheckSerializable(type))
    {
        throw new SerializationException(Environment.GetResourceString("Serialization_NonSerType", new object[] { type.FullName, type.Module.Assembly.FullName }));
    }
```

lets check CheckSerializable method of FormatterServices class:

```
private static bool CheckSerializable(RuntimeType type)
{
    return type.IsSerializable;
}
```

This code similar to:

```
    Type t = typeof (SomeClass);
    bool isTypeSerializable = t.IsSerializable;
```

In this example isTypeSerializable will be true if class SomeClass has SerializableAttribute. Otherwise false.
Soo... Simple answer: this attribute is **flag** which indicates that instances of class may be serialized. So it just needed and thats all.

Regarding your main question:
Unfortunately you can't use binary formatter for instance of class defined in silverlight assembly directly.
One way to do that to use a proxy class.
Example:
Class inside your silverlight assembly:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public bool BoolValue { get; set; }
}
```

Proxy class which supports serialization inside common .NET assemly with reference to silverlight assembly:

```
    [Serializable]
    public class SomeClassProxy
    {
        public int IntValue { get; set; }
        public string StringValue { get; set; }
        public bool BoolValue { get; set; }

        public static SomeClassProxy GetSerializableObject(SomeClass silverlightClass)
        {
            return new SomeClassProxy
                    {
                        IntValue = silverlightClass.IntValue,
                        StringValue = silverlightClass.StringValue,
                        BoolValue = silverlightClass.BoolValue
                    };
        }

        public static SomeClass DeserializeSilverlightCompatible(Stream stream)
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            SomeClassProxy proxy = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as SomeClassProxy;

            return new SomeClass
            {
                IntValue = proxy.IntValue,
                StringValue = proxy.StringValue,
                BoolValue = proxy.BoolValue
            };
        }
    }
```

So in your asp .net or winforms applications you should operate with proxy class:

```
    using(MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                            //create instance of silverlight class
            SomeClass mySilverlightClass = new SomeClass();
            mySilverlightClass.IntValue = 555;
            mySilverlightClass.StringValue = "Hello World!";
            mySilverlightClass.BoolValue = true;

            //<===serialize and take care of silverlight instance
            formatter.Serialize(memoryStream, SomeClassProxy.GetSerializableObject(mySilverlightClass));

            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            //===>deserialize to silverlight instance
            SomeClass mySilverlightClassRestored =  SomeClassProxy.DeserializeSilverlightCompatible(memoryStream);
        }
```

So this proxy takes care on both serialization and deserialization (after deserialization you'll receive instance of class SomeClass which defined in silverlight assembly).

If binary formatter is soft rescriction then I may recommend you to use xml serializer instead:

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeClass));
s.Serialize(memoryStream, mySilverlightClass);
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
SomeClass restored = s.Deserialize(memoryStream) as SomeClass;
```

It that case SerializableAttribute isn't needed.

Comment: My problem is that i have a silverlight assembly which is used by a silverilght application, a asp.net app and a winforms app, in my asp.net app and winforms app i need to serialize types defined in the shared silverlight assmebly. i am not looking at implementing binary serialization in my silverlight app

Comment: thanks for the reply, seems like a lot of work for a simple requirement.

Comment: @Vinay B R Yeah, thats true :) But anyway my suggestion - don't use BinarySerialization for SL. It's not natural way to serialize/deserialize data for Silverlight apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#if` directives to include serialization attributes (and code) for non-Silverlight builds:

```
#if !SILVERLIGHT
[Serializable]
#endif
public class SomeClass
{
}
```

Comment: as I understand question is: how to use binary serialization in Silverlight application, not how to avoid using of SerializableAttribute.

Comment: btw he uses silverlight assembly, that means he can't use SerializableAttribute at all.

Comment: My problem is that i have a silverlight assembly which is used by a silverilght application, a asp.net app and a winforms app, in my asp.net app and winforms app i need to serialize types defined in the shared silverlight assmebly. i am not looking at implementing binary serialization in my silverlight app

Comment: are you talking about using the same source files across 2 separate assemblies(a silverlight and a normal .net assembly). if so can elaborate a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out my serializer which is capable of moving binary data between .NET and Silverlight...  http://whydoidoit.com